# Incorrect CSS class for header with save sort widget

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, tablesorter

I am using the [rails-tablesorter gem](https://github.com/themilkman/jquery-tablesorter-rails) which is based on the recent version of tablesorter.

I use the save sort widget for my table, but it does not work exactly like the [demo](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-savesort.html).

My first column only contains links. If I click one of these and after the redirection hit backspace to go back to my table, it is correctly sorted, but the header of the sorted column has the class `tablesorter-headerUnSorted` instead of `tablesorter-headerAsc` or `tablesorter-headerDesc` and therefore no sort indicator is visible.

If I follow a link and use my navigation bar to get back to the table, it has the correct class.

For completeness my tablesorter init code, although there is nothing special:

```
  $(function() {
    $("#market-table").tablesorter({
      widgets: ["saveSort"],
      // Enable use of the characterEquivalents reference
      sortLocaleCompare : true,
      // maintain a stable sort (First Name column)
      sortStable : true,
      // if false, upper case sorts BEFORE lower case
      ignoreCase : true
    });
  });
```

Any idea what I might have done wrong or what the problem could be?
Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** I did some debugging, but still don't know, how I could fix this...

The following is the log for the case that it works (so me clicking the link on the navigation bar). I am not sure why the initialization is invoked two times. But the second seems to fix the headers and to actually sort the table.

In the case of me getting back to the table via backspace, tablesort initialization is only invoked once. The log equals the first entry from the log below.

```
Initializing tablesorter

Built headers: (3 ms)
[th.tablesorter-header.tablesorter-headerUnSorted, th.tablesorter-header.tablesorter-headerDesc, th.tablesorter-header.sorter-false.tablesorter-headerUnSorted]
  0: th.tablesorter-header.tablesorter-headerUnSorted
  1: th.tablesorter-header.tablesorter-headerUnSorted
  2: th.tablesorter-header.sorter-false.tablesorter-headerUnSorted
  length: 3__proto__: Object[0]

Detecting parsers for each column
Building cache for 29 rows (showing 5 rows in log) and 3 columns (3 ms)
Start initializing widgets
Completed initializing 1 widget (2 ms)
Start applying widgets
Completed applying 1 widget (2 ms)
Overall initialization time:  (28 ms)



Initializing tablesorter

Built headers: (3 ms)
[th.tablesorter-header, th.tablesorter-header, th.tablesorter-header.sorter-false]
  0: th.tablesorter-header.tablesorter-headerUnSorted
  1: th.tablesorter-header.tablesorter-headerDesc
  2: th.tablesorter-header.sorter-false.tablesorter-headerUnSorted
  length: 3__proto__: Object[0]

Detecting parsers for each column
Building cache for 29 rows (showing 5 rows in log) and 3 columns (2 ms)
Start initializing widgets
Completed initializing 1 widget (2 ms)
Applying sort 1,1 (1 ms)
Rebuilt table (3 ms)
Start applying widgets
Completed applying 1 widget (2 ms)
Start applying widgets
Completed applying 1 widget (2 ms)
Overall initialization time:  (28 ms)
```

Comment: I'm not sure why the savesort widget isn't applying. Set the `debug` option to `true` and see if there are any widget updates when you use the backspace.

Comment: There are, but the output regarding "Built headers" seems weird to me (take a look at my edit above). The log is from a working case. If it does not work (me hitting backspace) the log equals the first initialize block.

Comment: Hmm, what version are you using? The latest is v2.27.6.

Comment: Also, what version of the saveSort widget... I'm not seeing the `"saveSort: Last sort loaded:...."` message from it.

Comment: I use the rails gem in version 1.22.4, which is based on 2.27.6. saveSort widget is up to date too. `"saveSort: Last sort loaded:...."` is in the second init block, just collapsed a lot of the output to keep it clear.

Comment: Maybe it's an issue with rails (caching or sth). Are there supposed to be two initializing blocks? If so, there are probably also supposed to be two, if I hit backspace, right?

Comment: I just tried and removed turbolinks from my rails app. Backspace works now, but it would be nice to find a way without disabling page caching for my whole app. Anyway thanks for trying to help and sorry for bothering you.

Comment: It's not a bother!... I wonder if milkman can help. I'm not sure how to get ahold of him.

Answer (score 1):

So...the problem was rails' turbolinks caching the page.

After some google search, I found the solution on how to disable turbolink caching for a single page in [this Github issue](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks/issues/56).